# Yii2 - Kartik - Export - Exporting file isn't actually performed, although it shows it does

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to use yii2-export extention.
When I export, after pressing OK for the 'disable any popup...' message, the pop up window appears, but no download is being done.
My code:

```
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
$gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'idCandidate',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
];

echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
]);


echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,

    'exportConfig' => [
        GridView::HTML => [],
        GridView::CSV => [],

    ]
]);
```

[image]

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Try by changing 'pjax':true or 'pjax':false visa versa in your grid .

Comment: Did not help...

Comment: what you have used in <a href > "target_blank" or "target_self"  ?

Comment: I didn't configure the target. According to the documentation, the default is  'TARGET_POPUP'. I tried target_blank and target_self too, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try this http://demos.krajee.com/grid-excel-export ?